# I can see the preview of the layout but when i run the app the layout is not showing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a layout with 3 buttons. I worked on the second and the third button. When i press the second button the layout changes but when i press the third button the layout changes but its an empty layout.

This is the layout that should show up when i press the button:

```
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myappcompany.rob.basicphrases.Premium"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:text="PREMIUM SOUNDS"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="413dp"
        android:layout_height="614dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        app:columnCount="2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:rowCount="4">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="baiatuvreilepra"
            android:text="Baiatu vrei lepra?"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="cristelnitapopii"
            android:text="Baiat vrei lepra?"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="tagani"
            android:text="Baiatuu vrei lepra?"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:onClick="playPhrase"
            android:tag="tietisemaiscoalama"
            android:text="Baia vrei lepra?"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

but nothing show up , only an empty layout

This is the code of the layout that shows up emty:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;


public class Premium extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void playPhrase(View view){

        Button buttonPressed = (Button) view;

        Log.i("info", buttonPressed.getTag().toString());

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(buttonPressed.getTag().toString(),  "raw", getPackageName()));

        mediaPlayer.start();

    }
}
```

And this is the code of the main file with the intent:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        openActivity2();
        
    }

        public void openActivity2() {

            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oldSchool);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Premium.class));
                }
            });

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing something important here! You are missing `onCreate` and `setContentView`.

```
public class Premium extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_premium_YOUR_LAYOUT_NAME);
    }

    public void playPhrase(View view){

        Button buttonPressed = (Button) view;

        Log.i("info", buttonPressed.getTag().toString());

        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, getResources().getIdentifier(buttonPressed.getTag().toString(),  "raw", getPackageName()));

        mediaPlayer.start();

    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...